# Android DatePicker : Disabling the PREVIOUS dates based on the CURRENT date

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have a `DatePicker` in my app which is set in this way :

Layout :

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/traveltext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.11"
                android:text="Date Of Travel"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

             <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </EditText>

              <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCalendar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/date" >
        </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Global Values :

```
Button btnCalendar;
EditText txtDate;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
```

OnCreate :

```
btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);
    txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Method :

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnCalendar) {

        // Process to get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // Display Selected date in textbox
                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.show();
    }   }
```

Now my question is, how do i disable the PREVIOUS dates based on the CURRENT date?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // the callback received when the user "sets" the Date in the
    // DatePickerDialog
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearSelected,
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        year = yearSelected;
        month = monthOfYear + 1;
        day = dayOfMonth;
        // Set the Selected Date in Select date Button
        txtarrivedate.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
    }
};
```

// Method automatically gets Called when you call `showDialog()` method

```
   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 1:
        // create a new DatePickerDialog with values you want to show

        DatePickerDialog da = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Date newDate = c.getTime();
        da.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime());
        return da;
        // create a new TimePickerDialog with values you want to show
    case 2:
        // create a new DatePickerDialog with values you want to show
        DatePickerDialog da1 = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListener2, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();

        c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Date newDate2 = c1.getTime();
        da1.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate2.getTime());
        return da1;

    }
    return null;
}
```

only use use the for calling dialog
showDialog(1);

Comment: But it shows `IllegalArgumentException` for this line :

dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate2.getTime());

Comment: dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: Great, but why doesn't it identify `mDateSetListener` if i put `onDateSet`method inside button onClick? How do i fix this?

Comment: Yes now i have a small question :

What doesn't it work when i install it on my phone? I mean previous dates are selected which shouldn't happen.

Comment: in your phone which android os version ??

Comment: Its Android Jelly Bean 4.4

Answer (score 2):

**Simply try this solution:**

```
dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// set date picker with current date
DatePickerDialog date = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, mYear,mMonth,mDay){
            // Comapre the date selected in picker with the current date.      
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
            {   
                if (year < mYear)
                    view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                if (monthOfYear < mMonth && year == mYear)
                    view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                if (dayOfMonth < mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                    view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

            }
        };
        return date;
    }        

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // as soon as the dialog box is closed, this method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        mYear = selectedYear;
        mMonth = selectedMonth;
        mDay = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        txtDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1)
                .append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear)
                .append(" "));    

    }
};
```

Comment: Okay dude but the DatePickerDialog doesn't pop up once i click the button i.e btnCalendar(See in layout)
So where do i put the onClick?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually disable the date picker. But once the date is selected, you can validate it with current date and make the user reselect future date. You can send a toast message if the user selects the past date.

Comment: Date picker is just another option to generate the dates which you could get it from an edittext field. So I personally think this will be an easier way of doing things here.

Comment: Okay if it so, then please help me to validate the selected date with the current date. How do i do it?

Comment: You can get the current date with Calendar.getInstance();

Answer (score 0):

In your onDateSet you can validation on date like you want to set date only after today's date then add the following code in onDateSet method

```
            Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
            cl.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            if (cl.after(Calendar.getInstance())) { 
                    //set your date
            }else{
                    //do nothing
            }
```

hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

etDateOfDelivery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(SendOrderActivity.this,
                    new OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year,
                                int month, int day) {

                            if(month==intMonthOfYear && day<intDayOfMonth &&year<=intYear)
                            {
                                    // your message. dont use dialogmessage. its my custom dialog. use in your away
                                DialogMessage.customDialogSingleButton(context, "Invalid Date", "Please Set Comming Date", "Cancel");
                            }
                            else if(month<=intMonthOfYear && day==intDayOfMonth && year<=intYear)
                            {
                                DialogMessage.customDialogSingleButton(context, "Invalid Date", "Please Set Comming Date", "Cancel");
                            }
                            else if(month<=intMonthOfYear && day<=intDayOfMonth && year<intYear)
                            {
                                DialogMessage.customDialogSingleButton(context, "Invalid Date", "Please Set Comming Date", "Cancel");
                            }
                            else
                            {


                                if(month<9)
                                {
                                    etDateOfDelivery.setText("0"+(month + 1) + "/"
                                            + day+ "/" + year);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    etDateOfDelivery.setText((month + 1) + "/"
                                            + day+ "/" + year);
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }, intYear, intMonthOfYear, intDayOfMonth).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've set a button named startbtn and listener so that whenever user clicked on the button it'll prompt a date picker dialog and set the date to a TextView called startet

```
//getting calendar instance
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog startDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(Search.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    startet.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year);
                    startDay = dayOfMonth;
                    startMonth = month + 1;
                    startYear = year;
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            //Disable date before today
            startDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            startDatePicker.show();
        }
    });
```