# How to disable past dates?

Tags: android

How to disable past dates before current date using `datepickerdialog()` method?

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);   

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496947/android-datepicker-disabling-the-previous-dates-based-on-the-current-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [How set maximum date in datepicker dialog in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749361/how-set-maximum-date-in-datepicker-dialog-in-android)