# disable dates before today date in DatePickerDialog Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker

I want to disable the dates before today date in the DatePickerDialog .I am new in android please suggest me how could i do this .Here is my code that i have written for DatePickerDialog.

```html
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_arrival"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/arrivaldate"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_arrival"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Set"/>
```

```
 Button btn_arrival = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_arrival);

        txt_arrival = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_arrival);         
        myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();          

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {

                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                updateLabel();
            }
        };


        btn_arrival.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,date , myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);

            }

        });
private void updateLabel() {

        String myFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"; //In which you need put here.
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        txt_arrival.setText("Arrival Date on:" + sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

    }
```

Please suggest me what have to do.

Comment: See [this](http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.widget.DatePicker/setMinDate) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496947/android-datepicker-disabling-the-previous-dates-based-on-the-current-date/22497233#22497233)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this line of code

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

You can use it like this. I tested it and it works

```
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.m_button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatePickerDialog mDate = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date, 2016, 2, 24);
                mDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
                mDate.show();
            }
        });
    }

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            view.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: where can i put it on my code i write it on my code but i cannot put show method to display the datepicker i don't know if write it correct or not

Comment: I have tested my new code and it works. Check and see if it fits what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
start_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day

            // date picker dialog
            datePickerDialog1 = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                   dept_dayofWeek.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);


                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog1.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000); //disable previous dates
            datePickerDialog1.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have written quite an answer here but with very few informative comments. Please consider adding some commentary to the answer so that the other users would have an easier time navigating your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code and it works

```
final Calendar calendarEndDate = Calendar.getInstance();
YearEndDate = calendarEndDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
MonthEndDate = calendarEndDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
DayEndDate = calendarEndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
updateEndDisplay();
endDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatePickerDialog endDate = new DatePickerDialog(AttendandItemRequest.this,
                endDateSetListener,
                YearEndDate, MonthEndDate, DayEndDate);
        endDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        endDate.show();
    }
});
```